# coluna vazia no arquvio excel utilizando pandas

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

ao criar um arquivo do excel utilizando o codigo:

```
import pandas as pd

banco=pd.DataFrame({"Names": [], "Pay": [], "offices": []}).to_excel('teste.xlsx')

tabela=pd.read_excel('teste.xlsx')

print(tabela)
```

ele cria a primeira coluna vazia

como posso fazer para isso nãoa contecer ??

Answer (score 0):

Essa coluna "vazia" é o seu index que tem `True` como valor default. Para não inclui-lo no `.csv` que está sendo criado é só passar o parâmetro `False` para a propriedade.

Seu código funcionando fica assim:

```
import pandas as pd

banco=pd.DataFrame({"Names": [], "Pay": [], "offices": []}).to_excel('teste.xlsx', index=False)    
tabela=pd.read_excel('teste.xlsx')

print(tabela)
```

[Mais informações aqui.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)